# How does sound propagate in a superfluid?

Tags: acoustics, superfluidity

I was reading a lot of amazing properties on superfluid, like how it climbs the inner walls of the container using nothing but sheer van der Waals force, and also helium is very light element. Then I realized helium don't really reacts with each other that much so I wonder how do sound propagate through this superfluid particularly the speed of sound in it?

Comment: I don't know a lot about it, but I know the concept of second sound (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_sound) is associated with acoustics of superfluids.  Hopefully this directs your search in a fruitful direction!